Fredric Schuller's lecture notes for Classical Mechanics
In 2014, Dr. Friedric Sculler taught a course in German at FAU on classical mechanics. In one of the classes, he mentions sharing his detailed notes with the class which are in English.
The link for the course is provided below.
I have turned the whole of the internet upside down to look for those but I found only his lecture notes on "geometrical anatomy of physics" and quantum theory.
Does anybody have his lecture notes on classical mechanics or any clue how to find them?
I am tired of reading hand-wavy arguments presented in typical classical mechanics books.
Help needed.
https://www.fau.tv/course/id/272

hmm, I worked at DESY and don't know what FAU is. It's not ETH.

@JEB FAU is a (famous) German university.

Have you tried emailing Prof. Schuller? He seems like the best person to ask this to

Unfortunately, he does not reply to emails. And, yes, I tried it.

@NíckolasAlves It was just called "Erlangen" when I was there.

@JEB maybe you have friends in Erlangen who could help contact Prof.Schuller, and his former students, or have access to internal repositories or digital libraries of Erlangen. That would be very kind of you.

@TariqBY no can do, I've moved well beyond that stuff.

Is there a particular reason why you are so interested in this? I looked at some of Schuller's notes. They seemed to be a random rehash of basic mathematics with little relevance to physics to me. If you are trying to learn some deep dark secrets of nature with this teaching methodology, then you will be disappointed. We know that every single theory in physics is merely an approximation. What is important is to know where these approximations break down. No amount of mathematical dissection can tell you that. It's defined by the current limits of experimental physics.

@FlatterMann First of all, with due respect, Prof. Schuller's notes are not a random rehash. On the contrary, it is a noble quest to demand physicists stop using hand-wavy arguments, eventually leading to confusion when students try to wrestle with cutting-edge experimental or theoretical physics.

Secondly, the answer is hidden in the phrase, "We know that every single theory in ....................these approximations break down." If we do not have a solid understanding of theory in the first place, we will not be able to grasp all the scenarios where it breaks down and, most importantly, why it breaks down. I strongly believe that's the reason why physics has been stuck for the past 30-40 years.

@FlatterMann Schuller gives, IMHO, very well-structured and organized lectures, with deep insights. I think he motivates why one needs certain mathematical structures, also from an experimental/physics point of view, a lot. I also like his humor. -- and I think I am not alone with this opinion, as his lectures are quite popular and well-received. But as usual, this is to a large extend a matter of taste, and you are free to disagree.

@TariqBY It is not a hand-waving argument that mathematical logic and set theory are merely extrapolations of the behavior of classical objects in baskets. You can't learn anything about reality by looking at them because they came from reality to begin with. The same is true for Euclidean geometry and Riemannian manifolds. They are results that were derived from observations of nature. If you want to learn something about nature then you have to look at nature. Math is merely the distillation of what you have learned from observation.

@TariqBY Are you aware that Newton's laws simply don't apply to the physics on Earth's surface? The closest approximation we have in a human accessible environment is the volume inside the International Space Station. That is what Newtonian physics looks like (and even there friction gets in the way). Things sticking to the floor due to gravity do not implement Newton's first, second and third laws. So much for "theory" being a useful guide to nature. It gets worse as you go up the chain to Hamiltonian mechanics, classic field theory and quantum mechanics.

@FlatterMann I perfectly understand your argument with respect I completely disagree with you. This discussion needs an in-person meeting with black coffee at a big library surrounded by books. haha.  By the way, Newton's laws apply on Earth's surface, however, the concept of absolute space breaks down when we fail to have the inertial frame of reference. We need hardcore mathematics to understand our world because our common sense breaks down pretty quickly. have a nice day. stay blessed.

@TariqBY If Hamiltonian mechanics were the correct theory of mechanical motion, then we would have absolutely no need for lubricants. In reality, though, that's a $120 billion industry and without its products most machines on Earth would literally grind to a halt in a few seconds. So, yes, I would love to buy you a coffee, but that won't change the facts. Physical theories are approximations. How well they work depends on the individual system. No amount of math can help with that. It has to be established by experiments, just like the correct quantity and quality of gear and axle lubricant.

Wow. I found it. It's called Newton-Cartan theory. A rigorous mathematical treatment of Newton's theory. Which connects it pretty nicely with the theory of relativity.
If you are interested look for

A. Trautman's research papers on Newton-Cartan theory.
Lectures on general relativity, volume one, 1964, Brandeis Summer Institute in theoretical physics
Newton–Cartan gravity, Lecture notes by Philip Schwartz

